# Nonsingular map of quotient vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map and $W,U$ subspaces of $V$(finite dimensional ) with $W \subseteq U$. Also both spaces are $T$-invariant. If the induced map $V/W \to V/W $ is nonsingular then the induced map $V/U \to V/U $ is also nonsingular. I think the proof must be trivial but I cannot see it.

Comment: Are you assuming $V$ finite-dimensional? If not, what is the definition of "nonsingular"?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, V is finite dimensional.

Comment: In that case, note that since $(V/W) / (U/W) \cong V/U$, and $U/W$ is invariant under the induced map, we can assume that $W = \{0\}$. That makes things a little simpler. Then it's just dimension-counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T_W\colon V/W\to V/W$ and $T_U\colon V/U\to V/U$ be the induced maps.

Let $x\in V$; then, by assumption, there exists $y\in V$ with $T_W(y+W)=x+W$. In other words, $T(y)-x\in W$, hence also $T(y)-x\in U$. Therefore $T_U(y+U)=T(y)+U=x+U$ and $T_U$ is surjective.

You can see it “diagrammatically”: if $\pi\colon V/W\to V/U$ is the canonical map, the following diagram is commutative
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V/W @>T_W>> V/W \\
@V\pi VV @VV\pi V\\
V/U @>T_U>> V/U
\end{CD}
$$
Since $\pi\circ T_W$ is surjective, also $T_U$ is surjective.